# KDE taskbar and desktop break

Tags: taskbar, kde-plasma

It's happened a few times that my desktop and taskbar break, and I don't know how to restore them.

How do they break?  Well, the taskbar (I'm not sure it's called that, the one in the bottom with applications and notifications and kickoff button) disappears.

I'm also missing the desktop background and the widgets.

I can operate okay because I can move through windows and desktops, and use the F2-other command prompt to look for applications.  The way I'm restoring though is to restart the computer, but I figure there's a better way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system application that deals with this is `plasmashell`.  I just had to open krunner and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

opening krunner:
press alt and spacebar
then type 
*konsole*
which gives you a konsole window
then do 
*killall plasmashell*
-- wait until dead taskbar/launcher has gone.
then start it again by doing 
*plasmashell*